# Save to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, blazor

I would like to save data or values like with html and use them again when the page is called up again. I have here an example from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp how it works in html, does the whole thing also work in blazor?

```js
function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to lose your data that has been added to your html in postback?

Comment: For example, I would like to store a variable that a user has set locally so that it is saved for the next time. As in the example I wrote from w3 schools. The counter continues when call the page again at the place where, it had stopped, although the page was closed, .

Comment: Naturally, whenever postback happens in an HTML or any webpages you will lose the client information .your only option is to save data somewhere in the backend and use it in each postback

Comment: Ah okay, so its possible to save the data in my backend. But do i have to store it in my local storage ?

Comment: you can use sessions, cookies, and also databases to keep your data in each postback but not on the client-side, and for example in a simple variable, after posting data you can save anything anywhere

Comment: Ok, perfect thank you. I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality Blazor can only access the browser local storage via JavaScript - WASM doesn't have access directly.

However it's much easier if you use a library such as https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage - this will provide the necessary JS and can be injected as a service.

Comment: Perfect thanks i will check that. :)